# How to publish photoalbums to Facebook from website

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I'm currently working on a website backend which allows the administrator to manage photoalbums.

Besides, we have a Facebook page and we'd like to let the website and FB-page interact between each other.

The pictures are stored on the server the backend is hosted on. Now I'd like to know if it's possible, using the Facebook API, to publish a link to the photoalbum along with a thumbnail to the FB-page?

Untill now I've only worked with the FB API to put some Like buttons on my website, so I don't know if this is possible.